# Grouping range columns in SAS EG

Tags: sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I'm importing data into SAS that is divided into columns by monetary value. The data in the columns is a count of how many people fit into that category.

```
Income_0-50K  Income_50-100K  Income_100K+
5             10              5
```

Once imported, I'd like to group the original data into only two columns to look like this:

```
Income_0_100K  Income_100K+
15             5
```

How do I do this using PROC SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The term you want is creating a calculated field.

```
proc sql;
  select name, age, sex,
    (703*weight/(height**2)) as bmi
  from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

You `select` the calculation directly, so in my example the calculation is `703*weight/(height**2)`, and then you add `as [name]` where you replace `[name]` with your desired new column name.

If you don't want the original variables stored on the new dataset, just exclude them from the `select` as I did above.  If you want to use `select *` but still want to exclude the variables, you can `drop` them:

```
proc sql;
  create table bmi(drop=height weight) as
  select *,
    (703*weight/(height**2)) as bmi
  from sashelp.class;
quit;
```